# c++ this is insertion sorting for food and price and calorie but the sorting function doesn't work

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #ifndef FOOD_H
    #define FOOD_H
    using namespace std;
```

this class for insertion sorting for food's price or food's calorie

```
    class Food 
    {
        private:
          string Name;
          float Calorie;
          float Price;
          
        public:
        void setName(string n);
        void setCalorie(float c);
        void setPrice(float p);
        string getName();
        float getCalorie();
        float getPrice();
        
         Food();
         Food(string n,float c,float p); 
         void Print(Food FoodArray[],int);
         void Sort(Food FoodArray[], float);
         void Sort2(Food FoodArray[], float);
    };
    #endif
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Food.h"
#ifndef IMPLEMENTER_CPP
#define IMPLEMENTER_CPP
using namespace std;

void Food::setName(string n){Name=n;}
void Food::setPrice(float p){Price=p;}
void Food::setCalorie(float c){Calorie=c;}
string Food::getName(){return Name;}
float Food::getPrice(){ return Price;}
float Food::getCalorie(){ return Calorie;}
Food::Food(string n,float c,float p)
{
    Food::Name=n;
    Food::Calorie=c;
    Food::Price=p;
}
Food::Food()
{
    Food::Name="";
    Food::Calorie=0.00;
    Food::Price=0.00;
}

void Food::Print(Food FoodArray[],int num)
{
for (int i=0;i>num;i++)
{
cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"NAME: "<<FoodArray[i].getName()<<"     CALORIE: "<<FoodArray[i].getCalorie()<<"      PRICE: "<<FoodArray[i].getPrice()<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
}

}
    
void Food::Sort(Food FoodArray[], float pri)
{
   int i,j;
   float tmp;
   string t;
   
    for(i=1;i<=pri-1;i++)
    {
        tmp=FoodArray[i].getPrice();    
        t=FoodArray[i].getName();
        j=i-1;
 
        while((tmp<FoodArray[j].getPrice())&&(j>=0))
        { 
            FoodArray[j+1]=FoodArray[j];  
            j--;
        }
       
        FoodArray[j+1].setName(t);  
        FoodArray[j+1].setPrice(tmp); 
    }
 
    cout<<endl<<"Sorted list is shown below: "<<endl;
    
}

void Food::Sort2(Food FoodArray[], float cal)
{
       int i, j;
       float tmp;
       string t;
   
    for(i=1;i<=cal-1;i++)
    {
        tmp=FoodArray[i].getCalorie();
        t=FoodArray[i].getName();
        j=i-1;
 
        while((tmp<FoodArray[j].getCalorie())&&(j>=0))
        {
            FoodArray[j+1]=FoodArray[j];    
            j=j-1;
        }
 
        FoodArray[j+1].setCalorie(tmp); 
        FoodArray[j+1].setName(t);  
    }
 
    cout<<endl<<"Sorted list is shown below: "<<endl;
}


#endif
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Food.h"
#include "Implementer.cpp"
using namespace std;
```

contains the main method. From this class an array of food will be created and the sorting function
will be called to sort the array.

```
class client
{ 
    public:
    Food *foodArray[];
    void info()
    {int num; 
    string name,answer;
    float calorie,price;        
    loop2:
    cout<<"how many do you want ?  ";
    cin>>num;
    if (num>0)
    {
    
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<"- ";
        cout<<"Enter Food name: ";
        cin>>name;
    
        cout<<"Enter Calories: ";
        cin>>calorie;
    
        cout<<"Enter Price: ";
        cin>>price;
        Food food=Food(name,calorie,price);
        *foodArray[i]=food;
     }  
     
    foodArray[num]->Print(*foodArray,num);
        
    loop:
    cout<<"Would you like to sort the foods based on Price or Calories? P/C"<<endl;
    cin>>answer;
    if (answer=="P")
    {
    
            foodArray[num]->Sort(*foodArray,price);
            foodArray[num]->Print(*foodArray,num);
    }
    
    else if (answer=="C")
    {
    
        foodArray[num]->Sort2(*foodArray,calorie);
        foodArray[num]->Print(*foodArray,num);
    }
    
    else
    {
        cout<<"please choose P or C."<<endl;
        goto loop;
    }
    }
    else
    {
        goto loop2;
    }       
    }
};


    int main()
{   
    client C;
    C.info();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question? Please take the [tour] and read [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: Unless this is a homework question, were you are not allowed to use STL-features, I'd recommend to simply use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) instead of writing your own sorting function.

Comment: Please isolate the problem and provide a minimal working example of the problem. It won't help others to provide you hands if you provide all the project file.

Comment: Why did you start with an array of pointers? `*foodArray` is the pointer which is the first array element, not a pointer *to* the first array element. (And you never initialize your array or allocate any `Food`, and C++ does not allow unspecified-length array members. I think you need to read some more about arrays and pointers in your favourite C++ book.)

Comment: the problem is when i choose price or calorie the sort function doesn't works .. i mean the output is empty .

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour, so it's just bad luck that it does anything at all.

Comment: Ah but you're not sorting. Check the inner while loop, it's overwriting where it should be swapping the elements instead. Using a step-through debugger or online c++ editor should give you ample ways to find it yourself, if not by printing out the sequences.

Comment: it says no error but y no output .. also i took the function from the book and i fixed it a little bit

Comment: @HlaHakim When you fixed it a little bit, you actually broke it. (["Verschlimmbesserung"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verschlimmbesserung)  in German.)